# Check yaml file sorting using bash

Tags: bash, validation, sorting

I have a yaml file which describes directories on the server. I need a short script which will check that sections is sorted alphabetically by name. If some section will be inserted not alphabetically, need to point where it should be specified. File looks like(path and permission is optional parameters):

```
-
  name: scripts 
  description: execution scripts
  path: /home/user/scripts

-
  name: tests
  description: directory with tests
  path: /home/user/tests
  permissions: default
...
```

Can you suggest the best way how do this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
$ diff -u <(grep name: yaml) <(grep name: yaml | sort)

--- /dev/fd/11  2016-05-24 20:30:39.000000000 +0200
+++ /dev/fd/12  2016-05-24 20:30:39.000000000 +0200
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
-  name: tests
   name: scripts
+  name: tests
```

Where `yaml` is the file?